# How to find out if a row of one table exists in the values of at least one row of another table?

Tags: sql

I have two SQL tables, example below:

Table 1 (column types varchar, integer, numeric)

| A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A007 | 22 | 14.02 | _Z 1 |
| A008 | 36 | 15.06 | _Z 1 |

Table 2 (column types varchar)

| A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A009,A010,A011 | 33,35,36 | 16.06,17.06 | _Z 1,_Z 2 |
| A003,A007,A009 | 14,22,85 | 13.01,17.05,14.02 | _Z 1 |

Is there a way to compare individual rows of the first table with the rows of the second table and find out which row of the first table does not occur in the values of any row of the second table?

As can be seen, the first row of table 1 occurs in the values of the second row of table 2.

However, the second row of table 1 does not occur in the values of the rows of table 2, therefore the desired output is row 2 of table 1.

Desired output table:

| A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A008 | 36 | 15.06 | _Z 1 |

What I have tried so far:

My solution was to create a table containing all possible combinations of column values for each row of the second table (with the same column data types as the columns of the first table) and then use SELECT * FROM TABLE1 EXCEPT SELECT * FROM TABLE2 to get the difference rows.

The solution worked (for relatively small tables) but I am currently in a situation where generating all combinations of column values for each row of the second table (which in my case has 500 rows) results in a table containing millions of rows, so I am looking for another solution, where I can use the original table with 500 rows.

Thank you in advance for any possible answer, preferably one that could also work in the IBM DB2 database.

Comment: Wait a second, you are storing multiple values in one single column? This violates NF1 already and will just introduce trouble (consider all this string parsing necessary); you should consider a redesign...

Comment: What is your _version_ of SQL (e.g. MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle, Postgres)?  We need to know this in order to give a specific answer.

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen IBM DB2

Comment: @Aconcagua Yes (if i understand your question correctly), the multiple values in cell of table 2 are stored as a single varchar value. However, until now I had the data in Excel and generate combinations there. The form of the redesign attempt was the generation of a table of possible combinations.

Comment: As soon as you introduce string parsing your data base becomes inefficient. Rather try setting it up correctly, you'd get better performance then.

Comment: @Aconcagua I understand, but the table will only be used temporarily for the purpose of checking and subsequently deleted from the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use a `LIKE` trick here along with string concatenation:

```sql
SELECT t1.*
FROM Table1 t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM Table2 t2
    WHERE ',' || t2.A || ',' LIKE '%,' || t1.A || ',%'
);
```

Note that it would be a preferable table design for `Table2` to not store CSV values in this way.  Instead, get every `A` value onto a separate row.

Comment: Well there is no such type as CSV string of dates, it must be text.  As for checking a single value, if it's a date and you want to concatenate with a string, you should cast the former to text first.

Comment: @Tim I was skeptical about this solution but it seems to work :) One question, is there any change in structure needed when comparing DATE and VARCHAR data type?

Comment: Read my reply in the comment above.